# Encrypting data in Node.js?

Tags: html, node.js, encryption, cryptography

I want to encrypt user password and save encrypted password in database.
which encryption algorithm should i use ?
what is the best way to use crypto in nodejs for encryption/decryption process ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SALT and HASH password in nodejs w/ crypto](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17201450/salt-and-hash-password-in-nodejs-w-crypto)

Comment: This is both opinion-based and too broad as asked. There are any number of ways to do this--pick one (but please don't do your own crypto).

Comment: You want to hash passwords, not encrypt them.  Use bcrypt, or if that is not available, PBKDF2.

Comment: @LukeJoshuaPark : thanks, hashing is right technique in case of storing password

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a very basic implemenation to give you an idea, please look at what it does and read the crypto documenation on nodejs.org.

```
import { pbkdf2Sync, randomBytes } from 'crypto';

export class PasswordHash {
  private iters = 1e1; // TODO: increase later
  private keylen = 64;
  private digest = 'sha512';

  create(password) {
    const salt = randomBytes(128).toString('base64');

    const hash = pbkdf2Sync(password, salt, this.iters, this.keylen, this.digest).toString('base64');

    return [salt, hash, this.iters].join('::');
  }

  verify(stored, password) {
    const [salt, hash, iters] = stored.split('::');
    const verify = pbkdf2Sync(password, salt, parseInt(iters, 10), this.keylen, this.digest);

    return hash === verify.toString('base64');
  }
}
```