# NodeJS JSON.parse(...) takes forever to finish (under debugger in WebStorm)

Tags: json, node.js, webstorm

## EDIT

The problem seems to be related to WebStorm itself, it seems that it doesn't want to work with objects containing huge amount of nested objects. Neither it wants to show the object contents inside Watches window. The problem is kinda strange because I'm able to inspect the string, it is loaded blazingly fast. Seems like a WebStorm issue

---

I have a relatively big JSON file 4.9mb that I need to process in NodeJS, the file is stored in file system and is loadded using following lines of code:

```
var path = require('path');

var filename = path.join(__dirname, 'db_asci.json');
var fs = require('fs');

var content = fs.readFileSync(filename);

debugger;
var decycledObj = JSON.parse(content);
debugger;
```

The problem is that after the first `debugger;` breakpoint is hit, the second one is not, I'm waiting for more than 20 minutes and nothing, one processor core is loadded at 100%. I'm unable to debug the function because it's native.

[Here](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/51743054/db_asci/db_asci.zip) is ASCI version of JSON

[Here](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/51743054/db_asci/db_asci.zip) is UTF8 version of JSON

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem you are running in to is **not** JSON parsing taking too long.  Indeed, try this:

```
var start = Date.now();
var obj = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync(filename));
console.log('Took', Date.now() - start, 'ms');
```

You'll probably see that it took less than a second or so.

What you are running into is an issue with *the debugger itself* – the observer effect.  The act of observing a system changes that system.

I assume you're using node-inspector.  Whenever you have an extremely large, complex object, it is extremely expensive to load the object into the inspector.  While it is doing so, your node process will peg the CPU and the event loop is paused.

My guess is that the JSON is parsed and a huge (given that we're dealing with 5MB) object is created.  Node then hits the second `debugger`, and the inspector needs to load locals.  The excruciatingly slow process begins, and the inspector won't show that you've hit a breakpoint until it finishes.  So to you it just looks frozen.

Try replacing your JSON file with something small (like `{a:1}`).  It should load quickly.

---

Do you really need to visually inspect the entire object?  There are tools better suited for viewing JSON files.

Comment: But I'm able to observe the string (I'm using WebStorm) the string is also 5mb in size and it is being loaded as fast as... Well, it is loaded fast...

Comment: But it really seems is a debugger issue, so your post seems to be the answer to the question.

Answer (score 2):

+1 for Pradeep Mahdevu solution, here is another way to the same thing, (edit with the async version)

```
var fs = require ('fs');
var options = { encoding: 'utf8' };
var jsonData = fs.readFile('db_asci.json', options, function (err, data) {
  if (err) throw err;
  var object = JSON.parse(data);
});
```

Comment: How is that any different from OPs original solution?

Comment: `readFileSync` is just .... no http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13822085/fs-readfilesync-seems-faster-than-fs-readfile-is-it-ok-to-use-for-a-web-app-in

Comment: @f0x-that's not what the question was about either. It was about the parse time.

Comment: I downloaded the file he posted, and run those 3 lines, and it worked in less than a second.
Perhaps you can check in the first debug if your content var is non empty. The only difference is the path and the encoding param.

Answer (score 1):

You can [require](http://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#modules_file_modules) .json files. So, no need to parse.

```
var content = require('./db_asci.json');
```

That should do it!

Comment: Why would that be faster?

Comment: This does absolutely nothing special.  When you `require` a file ending in .json, [all it does is call `fs.readFileSync` and pass that to `JSON.parse`](https://github.com/joyent/node/blob/v0.10.21/lib/module.js#L479-487).  In other words, *exactly* what the OP is already doing.