# How to structure a Node Js blog with marked md parser

Tags: javascript, node.js, markdown

Currently working on creating a simple blog engine using NodeJS / Express4.
I want to publish the blog posts using the markdown language.

I have found marked: https://github.com/chjj/marked and it is perfect for what I need, and have created a real basic solution to grab the data from an md file and display it in a client.

The issue I am having is with actually fitting my solution into the correct MVC structure of a NodeJS application. Here is what I have produced, this works for one md file - in index.js:

```
app.get('/test', function(req, res) {
  var path = __dirname + '/node_modules/marked/doc/todo.md';
  var file = fs.readFileSync(path, 'utf8');
  res.send(marked(file.toString()));
});
```

I have also found a solution to recursively scan a particular directory to get all the blog posts (in md) using walk:

```
var walker  = walk.walk('./node_modules/marked/doc', { followLinks: false });
walker.on('file', function(root, stat, next) {
  console.log(root + '/' + stat.name);
  next();
});
```

How can I concatenate multiple md posts into one html response in the correct manor - other page requests go like:

```
var users = require('./routes/users');
app.use('/users', users);
```

in index.js, then

```
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
  res.render('users', { title: 'Express' });
});
```

in routes users.js

I have tried something like:

```
var string = '';
app.get('/test', function(req, res) {
  walker.on('file', function(root, stat, next) {
    var path = __dirname + root + '/' + stat.name;
    var file = fs.readFileSync(path, 'utf8');
    string += (marked(file.toString()));
    next();
  });
  res.send(string);
});
```

this doesn't work, and it definitely isn't the best solution.
Any suggestions?

Comment: The first thing you might want to think about is your use of synchronous IO in a Node app.  See for instance, http://stackoverflow.com/a/13823336/1243641.

Comment: Hi yeah, I was thinking about integrating promises, but for now, just wanted the core functionality ..

Comment: Well, even just using the normal `fs.readFile` with its callbacks rather than `fs.readFileSync` would help.  That's not the cause of your issue, though...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this (entirely untested) might help:

```
app.get('/test', function(req, res) {
  var string = '';

  walker.on('file', function(root, stat, next) {
    var path = __dirname + root + '/' + stat.name;
    var file = fs.readFileSync(path, 'utf8');
    string += (marked(file.toString()));
    next();
  });

  walker.on('end', function() {
    res.send(string);
  });

  walker.walk(/* whatever */);
});
```

Comment: Sorry, I haven't actually used that file walker.  It *looks* like it should works.  :-)

Comment: no problem, thanks for the suggestion, could you perhaps suggest a different method of traversing a directory that you know to work

Comment: got your solution working using fs, I guess the walks recursive method causes the problems -- this is good as I would like to use as little additional packages as possible

Comment: Well, glad it worked.  Sorry I haven't had any time to look into it.