# Will running promises and immediately sending response in express block anything?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, asynchronous

I just read this great SO question & answer about how doing `async`/`await` will not block a thread: [Will async/await block a thread node.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46004290/will-async-await-block-a-thread-node-js)

I wanted to sanity check something when doing this in the context of Express.js.

Will the following  code block any process and/or will express let `runAsyncMethodThatReturnsPromise` complete in the background:

```
const myEndpoint = async(req, res) => {
  const users = await DB.getSomeUsers();
  users.forEach(user => {
    user.runAsyncMethodThatReturnsPromise();
  });

  res.send('Ok');
}
```

Comment: You are right, `user.runAsyncMethodThatReturnsPromise();` will run in the background and will not block the event loop :)

Comment: @Thom So when I run a method in the router of express, is it basically awaiting on its own promise that resolves the second I call `res.send` and that is the only thing that blocks a thread?

Comment: It really depends on how `runAsyncMethodThatReturnsPromise()` is implemented. Just because it returns a promise doesn't mean it's not a CPU-bound function.

Comment: Yes, and I don't think that is blocking the thread. You might be mixing two different things: thread blocking and async/await. There is only a few things that might actually block the event loop/thread. You can read more about that [here](https://nodejs.org/uk/docs/guides/dont-block-the-event-loop/).

Comment: For example `runAsyncMethodThatReturnsPromise() { return new Promise(() => { for (let i = 0; i < 1e9; ++i) { } }); }` _will_ block the event loop.