# Why we should/should not use async await in nodejs with express

Tags: node.js, express

**I am fairly new to node and using express with it.**

---

I have a simple API which gets data from mongo in this way:

1. From a `Router` I call a async method in `AccountServices`*(which is in a different file)* called `getAccountDetails`
2. `getAccountDetails` in turn gets data from mongo making an async call.
3. I don't want to pass `req`,`res` objects to the `getAccountDetails` function, So I've use `async` `await` and it works perfectly.

What I want to understand is does my whole thread/api goes into wait state for that `async` `await` function to resolve?

If So, how can I overcome this.

Comment: No, it does not. Consider async-await as syntactic sugar for promises. It works like a promise but looks like a synchronous code

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Will async/await block a thread node.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46004290/will-async-await-block-a-thread-node-js)

Answer (score 1):

async/await functions are asynchronous which means that the rest of your code doesn't wait for them to finish. They are very useful for operations like fetching data since you can't predict the time it'll take which would potentially end up freezing your app for seconds or even minutes.